# The integral of ${x^2 - 1 \over x^3 \sqrt{2x^4 - 2x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int {x^2 - 1 \over x^3 \sqrt{2x^4 - 2x^2 + 1}}dx$$

---

Substituting $u = x^2$, I get $${1\over 4}\int {u - 1 \over u^2 \sqrt{2u^2 - 2u + 1}}du$$

Then completing the square under the square root.

$${1\over 4}\int {u - 1 \over u^2 \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2} u - \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right)+ 1/2} }du$$

Substituting $\tan z = \sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2} u - \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right)$

$${ \sqrt{2} \over 4}\int {\tan z -3 \over (\tan z- 1)^2 } \times \sec z \  dz$$

I think I can solve the last integral if I think a bit more but I need a better way to solve this question, this was seems very tedious.

Comment: You are mixing $u$ and $x$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan No I don't think so, Where ?

Comment: You can't see? Its clear from you post? Integrand in terms of $u$ and used $dx$?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan That is just copy paste error, I edited it.

Comment: Per [this meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex), please consider incorporating some text in your titles.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I felt that my title is self explanatory.

Comment: I agree but, if you read the linked meta thread, you'll find that's not at all the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint pull out $x^2$ common from numerator and $x^4$ in the root from denominator ie $x^2$ from numerator. Then put $1-\frac {1}{x^2}=u $ thus $\frac {2}{x^3}dx=du $ also write the new denominator as $1+(1-\frac {1}{x^2})^2$ hope you can handle  from  here.

Comment: Is the answer $$ \sqrt{2x^4 - 2x^2 + 1}\over 2x^2$$ ??

Comment: Yes hope you got it by putting u =tan (t,)

Comment: Yes I got it by tangent substitution. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!